# How can I control "View Whitespace between pages" in MS Word using VBA/Macros?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to control the Tools->Options->View->"View Whitespace between pages" through VBA/Macros?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that these settings
>   appear to be changing in a random
>   manner

Actually your clueless users are clicking between the pages and hiding the whitespace. It's another simple click to get it back.

To do it programmatically see this link:

http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DocumentEvents.htm

Add a AutoOpen macro into everyone's Normal.Dot template and add the line

```
ActiveWindow.View.DisplayPageBoundaries = True
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my description to remove the stuff about the users before I saw your answer.

Comment: ... ActiveWindow.View.DisplayPageBoundaries is exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DJ is right on with:

```
ActiveWindow.View.DisplayPageBoundaries = True
```

However, I would caution against altering the `Normal.dot` template to automate formatting. This template affects the function of Word universally, and the end user needs to be in control of their own macros & shortcuts (even if the end user doesn't write/use macros presently).

An example of a drawback is that headers/footers may become invisible, and may frustrate end users who want to work with and view headers/footers if the default active document keeps opening with this area obscured.

[The Word MVP pages](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/PseudoAutoMacros.htm) DJ suggested are excellent, and I recommend digging even further to the section on "How to create global event procedures similar to AutoOpen, AutoNew and AutoClose, without using Normal.dot".

It may take several readings over, but it's worth the effort to understand how to create a non-default template that still performs "default" actions. Once you do this, adding or removing the code to make *any number* of macros available is as simple as adding your template file "xxxx.dotm" to the Word Startup folder, and removing the template file when the macros are no longer needed.

This removes the need to disentangle unwanted code from user's `normal.dotm` template later, or when you want to change or update code. There are plenty of other tricks that can be used automate the installation of macros, to give the end user better control over added-on macros, and to give you more control over writing and updating code, but this would be a good start.